# How to disable rule [plugin:vite:vue] Duplicate attribute

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have a Vue 3 app set up with Vite and Storybook.

I am trying to use two class attributes for a button, which I believe is perfectly valid:

```
    <button 
        :id="id"
        :type="type"
        @click="onClick"
        :class="classes"
        :class="{
            'bg-gray-100': disabled,
            'cursor-not-allowed': disabled,
            'inline-block': block,
            'w-full': block,
        }" 
        :disabled="disabled">{{ text }}<slot/></button>
```

Running the project, `npm run storybook`, gives me

```
[vite] Internal server error: Duplicate attribute.
  Plugin: vite:vue
```

Where and how do I disable this rule?

Comment: Hm, this may override each other at some point IMO. Why don't you add `classes` to your object notation? Like `{ classes: true, etc... }` or something alike should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `vue.js`, you can't have two `v-bind` for the same attributes on one element.

In your case you are putting twice the `classes` elements wich results in the `Duplicate attribute.` error.

To solve your problem, I would recommand mergind your classes attributes using a `computed` properties with the other classes you are trying to add.

```js
export default {
   computed: {
      mergedClasses(){
         return {...this.classes,
            'bg-gray-100': disabled,
            'cursor-not-allowed': disabled,
            'inline-block': block,
            'w-full': block,
        }
      }
   }
}
```

And use it in the template :

```html
<button 
        :id="id"
        :type="type"
        @click="onClick"
        :class="mergedClasses"
        :class="{
            'bg-gray-100': disabled,
            'cursor-not-allowed': disabled,
            'inline-block': block,
            'w-full': block,
        }" 
        :disabled="disabled">{{ text }}<slot/></button>
```

Comment: Ah, I now understood the difference from how I've used two class attributes (class and :class, but not both :class) before. Thank you so much for providing a solution!

Comment: Yep `class` and ` :class` are different for vue ;) do not hesitate to mark the answer if it's good for you

Comment: Actually, I ended up combining the string and the object with the array syntax `:class="[classes, {'bg-gray-100': disabled, … }]"`